# Does Libgdx work with the virtualbox and android x86?

Tags: android, virtualbox, libgdx

Running my app in the Android virtual machine in Eclipse works ok. But trying Android x86 through Virtual Box I get an error saying that the OS/phone is not applicable for the app.

Has anyone tried using libgdx with android x86?

Answer (score 4):

The x86 native libraries are not currently included with libGDX distrubtions, so its not going to work out of the box.  (Currently only two variations of ARM binaries are built and included.)

There is an [open issue](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/issues/detail?id=290) on the libGDX issue tracker. It looks like the hold up is some missing official support in the Android NDK for x86.

That said, it looks like it is *possible* to make the library build its native bits for x86, its just not stable enough to be included by default.  See [this forum post](http://www.badlogicgames.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=17&t=2576) for details.

Answer (score 1):

For reference seems this is available now as [mentioned here](http://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/?p=3103)

> To use the x86 natives, simply copy the x86/ folder from the nightlies to your Android project’s libs/ folder (next to the armeabi and armeabi-v7a folder). The setup-ui will not add those libraries for you automatically. I opted to do it this way for the time being as x86 Android devices are super rare, and you’d just blow up the size of your APK unnecessarily.